# SSLEngine Handshake stuck at second loop

Tags: java, ssl, sslengine

I'm trying to implement an SSL Handshake using SSLEngine, I need to do it both ways as a sever and as a client as well, however I'm stuck and I cannot figure it out why.

The handshake starts correctly, the Hello's are exchanged, the keys are exchanged, but then I'm getting into a NEED_UNWRAP state.

Here is the handshake code I'm using:

```
    protected boolean doHandshake(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, SSLEngine engine, Socket socket) throws IOException {

    Log.d(TAG,"About to do handshake...");
    Log.d(TAG,engine.getHandshakeStatus().toString());
    int dataSize;
    SSLEngineResult result;
    Log.d(TAG,"Line 1");
    HandshakeStatus handshakeStatus;
    Log.d(TAG,"Line 2");
    // NioSslPeer's fields myAppData and peerAppData are supposed to be large enough to hold all message data the peer
    // will send and expects to receive from the other peer respectively. Since the messages to be exchanged will usually be less
    // than 16KB long the capacity of these fields should also be smaller. Here we initialize these two local buffers
    // to be used for the handshake, while keeping client's buffers at the same size.

    if (socket!=null)
    {
        inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
        outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"Line 3");
    int appBufferSize = engine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize();
    Log.d(TAG,"Line 4");
    ByteBuffer myAppData = ByteBuffer.allocate(appBufferSize);
    Log.d(TAG,"Line 5");
    ByteBuffer peerAppData = ByteBuffer.allocate(appBufferSize);
    Log.d(TAG,"Line 6");
    try {
        myNetData.clear();
        peerNetData.clear();
    }
    catch (Exception e){Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());}
    Log.d(TAG,"Line 7");

    Log.d(TAG,"Line 8");
    handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
    Log.d(TAG,"Line 9");
    Log.d(TAG,"Before the while: " + (handshakeStatus != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.FINISHED && handshakeStatus != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NOT_HANDSHAKING));

    byte[] buffer=new byte[16384];
    while (handshakeStatus != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.FINISHED && handshakeStatus != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NOT_HANDSHAKING) {
        Log.d(TAG,handshakeStatus.toString());
        switch (handshakeStatus) {
        case NEED_UNWRAP:
            Log.d(TAG,"Got here...");
            buffer=new byte[16384];
            peerAppData.clear();
            int readdata=inputStream.read(buffer);
            Log.d(TAG,"Read data amount: " + readdata);
            if ( readdata < 0) {
                Log.d(TAG,"No data....");
                if (engine.isInboundDone() && engine.isOutboundDone()) {
                    return false;
                }
                try {
                    engine.closeInbound();
                } catch (SSLException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"This engine was forced to close inbound, without having received the proper SSL/TLS close notification message from the peer, due to end of stream.");
                }
                engine.closeOutbound();
                // After closeOutbound the engine will be set to WRAP state, in order to try to send a close message to the client.
                handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                break;
            }
           HackerService.bytesToHex(buffer);

            peerNetData.put(buffer,6,readdata-6);
            Log.d(TAG,"before data flipped...");
            peerNetData.flip();
            Log.d(TAG,"data flipped...");
            try {
                result = engine.unwrap(peerNetData, peerAppData);
                Log.d(TAG,"data unwrapped...");
                peerNetData.compact();

                Log.d(TAG,"data compacted...");
                handshakeStatus = result.getHandshakeStatus();
                Log.d(TAG,"Handshake status: " + handshakeStatus);
            } catch (SSLException sslException) {
                Log.e(TAG,"A problem was encountered while processing the data that caused the SSLEngine to abort. Will try to properly close connection..." + sslException.getMessage());
                engine.closeOutbound();
                handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                break;
            }
            switch (result.getStatus()) {
            case OK:
                break;
            case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                // Will occur when peerAppData's capacity is smaller than the data derived from peerNetData's unwrap.
                peerAppData = enlargeApplicationBuffer(engine, peerAppData);
                break;
            case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
                // Will occur either when no data was read from the peer or when the peerNetData buffer was too small to hold all peer's data.
                peerNetData = handleBufferUnderflow(engine, peerNetData);
                break;
            case CLOSED:
                if (engine.isOutboundDone()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    engine.closeOutbound();
                    handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid SSL status: " + result.getStatus());
            }
            break;
        case NEED_WRAP:
            myNetData.clear();
            Log.d(TAG,"Enetering need wrap");
            try {
                result = engine.wrap(myAppData, myNetData);
                Log.d(TAG,"Got a result" + myAppData.toString());
                handshakeStatus = result.getHandshakeStatus();
                Log.d(TAG,"Handskes is: " + handshakeStatus.toString());

            } catch (SSLException sslException) {
                Log.e(TAG,"A problem was encountered while processing the data that caused the SSLEngine to abort. Will try to properly close connection...");
                engine.closeOutbound();
                handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                break;
            }
            switch (result.getStatus()) {
            case OK :
                Log.d(TAG,"Case WRAP, OK");
                myNetData.flip();

             //  while (myNetData.hasRemaining()) {
                    byte[] arr = new byte[myNetData.remaining()+6];
                    myNetData.get(arr,6,myNetData.remaining());
                    arr[0]=0;
                    arr[1]=3;
                    arr[2]=(byte) ((arr.length-4)/256);
                    arr[3]=(byte) ((arr.length-4)%256);
                    arr[4]=buffer[4];
                    arr[5]=buffer[5];
                    HackerService.bytesToHex(arr);
                    outputStream.write(arr);
               // }
                break;
            case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                Log.d(TAG,"Case WRAP,OverFlow");
                // Will occur if there is not enough space in myNetData buffer to write all the data that would be generated by the method wrap.
                // Since myNetData is set to session's packet size we should not get to this point because SSLEngine is supposed
                // to produce messages smaller or equal to that, but a general handling would be the following:
                myNetData = enlargePacketBuffer(engine, myNetData);
                break;
            case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
                throw new SSLException("Buffer underflow occured after a wrap. I don't think we should ever get here.");
            case CLOSED:
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Before WRAP FLIP");
                    myNetData.flip();
                    Log.d(TAG,"After WRAP FLIP");
                    while (myNetData.hasRemaining()) {
                        Log.d(TAG,myNetData.toString());
                         arr = new byte[myNetData.remaining()];
                        myNetData.get(arr);
                        outputStream.write(arr);
                    }
                    // At this point the handshake status will probably be NEED_UNWRAP so we make sure that peerNetData is clear to read.
                    peerNetData.clear();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Failed to send server's CLOSE message due to socket channel's failure.");
                    handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid SSL status: " + result.getStatus());
            }
            break;
        case NEED_TASK:
            Log.d(TAG,"Need task");
            Runnable task;
            while ((task = engine.getDelegatedTask()) != null) {
                executor.execute(task);
            }
            handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
            break;
        case FINISHED:
            break;
        case NOT_HANDSHAKING:
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid SSL status: " + handshakeStatus);
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"Handshake completed");
    return true;

}
```

This is my SSLEngine creating class:

```
public static SSLEngine Builder(Context context) throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {
        InputStream openRawResource = context.getResources().openRawResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("mykey", "raw", context.getPackageName()));
        KeyStore instance = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        instance.load(openRawResource, "passcode".toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory instance2 = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        instance2.init(instance, "passcode".toCharArray());
        SSLContext instance3 = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        instance3.init(instance2.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[]{new TrustmanagerHelper()}, new SecureRandom());
        SSLEngine createSSLEngine = instance3.createSSLEngine();
        createSSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
        return createSSLEngine;

    }
```

When I'm attempting a handshake as a client. As you can see from the logs, I start in NEED_WRAP, send data to server, states gets to NEED_UNWRAP (which is correct) server responds, I parse the answer without any error, but instead of advancing to NEED_WRAP I get stuck in NEED_UNWRAP...

```
About to do handshake...
NEED_WRAP
Line 1
Line 2
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Before the while: true
NEED_WRAP
Enetering need wrap
Got a resultjava.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16384 cap=16384]
Handskes is: NEED_UNWRAP
Case WRAP, OK
ByteTohex: 00030088000316030100810100007D03030E62BFCFF988.......
NEED_UNWRAP
Got here...
Read data amount: 2296   (THIS MATCHES THE NUMBER OF BYTES SENT BY THE SERVER!!!!)
ByteTohex: 000308F40003160303005B0200005703035B203DA285349B7C88A76CA6AA3.....
before data flipped...
data flipped...
data unwrapped...
data compacted...
Handshake status: NEED_UNWRAP
NEED_UNWRAP
Got here...
```

If I try to do the handshake as a server, logs looks like this. As you can see from the logs, the first read is fine, I respond to the client, I get the second bit of data from the client, and instead of having a NEED_WRAP and being able to carry on with the handshake I'm hit with a NEED_UNWRAP message, but of course there is no more data to be read from the client....

```
    About to do handshake...
    NEED_UNWRAP
    Line 1
    Line 2
    Line 3
    Line 4
    Line 5
    Line 6
    Line 7
    Line 8
    Line 9
    Before the while: true
    NEED_UNWRAP
    Got here...
06-12 23:42:14.017 7523-7620/uk.co.borconi,emil.myapp D/MyApp: Read data amount: 297
06-12 23:42:14.020 7523-7620/uk.co.borconi,emil.myapp D/MyApp: ByteTohex: 00030125000316....
    before data flipped...
    data flipped...
06-12 23:42:14.029 7523-7620/uk.co.borconi,emil.myapp D/MyApp: data unwrapped...
    data compacted...
    Handshake status: NEED_WRAP
    NEED_WRAP
    Enetering need wrap
    Got a resultjava.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16384 cap=16384]
    Handskes is: NEED_UNWRAP
    Case WRAP, OK
06-12 23:42:14.030 7523-7620/uk.co.borconi,emil.myapp D/MyApp: ByteTohex: 00030881000316.....
    NEED_UNWRAP
    Got here...
06-12 23:42:14.038 7523-7620/uk.co.borconi,emil.myapp D/MyApp: Read data amount: 132
06-12 23:42:14.039 7523-7620/uk.co.borconi,emil.myapp D/MyApp: ByteTohex: 00030080000316....
    before data flipped...
    data flipped...
06-12 23:42:14.040 7523-7620/uk.co.borconi,emil.myapp D/MyApp: data unwrapped...
    data compacted...
    Handshake status: NEED_UNWRAP
    NEED_UNWRAP
    Got here...
```

I did had a look at some similar questions on StackOverflow before posting, but they were mainly about order being wrong, which I think I got right in this case... I'm pretty sure I'm missing the obvious, but I just cannot seem to figure it out...

Comment: You're taking too much for granted here. NEED_UNWRAP means you should do an `unwrap()`. If *that* causes BUFFER_UNDERFLOW, do a read. Similarly for NEED_WRAP `wrap()`, and BUFFER_OVERFLOW and `write().

Comment: @EJP - Thanks but this confuses me even more. After my wrap, the states gets into need_unwarp. I don't get to overflow state at all, if I don't do a write, how will the other party ever get the data? Also for unwrap, do of unwrap for nothing? I will certainly try but I'm not sure I follow the logic. Also reading NEED_UNWRAP documentation, clearly says that you need to read data from your input.

Comment: @EJP  - Doing unwrap without data results in TLS parse error and I never get to the overflow situation either. Also looking at Oracle docs, they also say that we should do read in unwarp and write in wrap ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#OperationStatus )

Comment: Doing `unwrap()` without data results in BUFFER_UNDERFLOW, whereupon you do the read, as I said, and then of course repeat the unwrap. But if you're using a buggy `SSLEngine` all bets are off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 2 days of chasing my own tale, I have finally found the problem as described here: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/5975

> I found that our stream-based wrapper around SSLEngine doesn't read
>   all incoming data from the SSLEngine when there is no new incoming
>   data from the network, so the application gets stuck waiting for
>   incoming data. After some debugging I found out that with netty's
>   openssl SSLEngine unwrap seems to produce plain text data in smaller
>   chunks (probably single TLS frames) and keeps buffering the rest of
>   the data internally. The src buffer is fully consumed but calling
>   unwrap again with an empty src buffer will still produce more data.
>   This differs from what the JDK SSLEngine does in two points:
>
> - the JDK SSLEngine consumes and produces as much data as possible in one go while the openssl one produces less output in one call
> - the JDK SSLEngine doesn't buffer encrypted data internally between calls to unwrap but "puts them back" into the src buffer

So even my code was "correct" I needed to do multiple loops so now my unwrap codes looks something like this:

```
peerNetData.put(buffer,6,readdata-6);
                Log.d(TAG,"before data flipped...");
                peerNetData.flip();
                Log.d(TAG,"data flipped...");
                try {
                    do {
                    result = engine.unwrap(peerNetData, peerAppData);
                    Log.d(TAG,"data unwrapped...");
                    Log.d(TAG,"Handskes is: " + result.getHandshakeStatus().toString() +" Current Status: " +result.getStatus() + " Bytes consumed: " + result.bytesConsumed() + " bytes produce: " + result.bytesProduced());
                    } while (peerNetData.hasRemaining() || result.bytesProduced()>0);
                    peerNetData.compact();


                    Log.d(TAG,"data compacted...");
                    handshakeStatus = result.getHandshakeStatus();
                    Log.d(TAG,"Handshake status: " + handshakeStatus);
                    .....................................................
```

Comment: So it's a bug in Netty. Why on earth do they provide their own `SSLEngine`? Masochism? NB The Java `SSLEngine` doesn't 'put them back', it just doesn't unwrap them.

Comment: We'll I'm just glad I finally come to the bottom of it. Now this does raise the question will I need to do something similar on every packet received after the handshake? If so this might kill the advantage of porting my code from jni+openssl to pure java to reduce overhead when passing data between Java and c.  Also it's possible that it's only broken in Android, I haven't tested outside android.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
 do {
                        result = engine.unwrap(peerNetData, peerAppData);
                        System.out.println("data unwrapped...");
                        System.out.println("Handskes is: " + result.getHandshakeStatus().toString() +" Current Status: " +result.getStatus() + " Bytes consumed: " + result.bytesConsumed() + " bytes produce: " + result.bytesProduced());

                        if(result.getHandshakeStatus() == SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NEED_TASK){
                            Runnable task;
                            while ((task = engine.getDelegatedTask()) != null) {
                                task.run();
                            }
                            handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                        }
                    } while (result.bytesProduced()>0 || peerNetData.hasRemaining());
```

Output:

```
data unwrapped...
Handskes is: NEED_TASK Current Status: OK Bytes consumed: 267 bytes produce: 0
data unwrapped...
Handskes is: NEED_UNWRAP Current Status: OK Bytes consumed: 6 bytes produce: 0
data unwrapped...
Handskes is: NEED_WRAP Current Status: OK Bytes consumed: 45 bytes produce: 0
OK
```

I guess it needed to do some processiing between the unwraps